# Fatal Error when PyQGIS searches for available providers: QgsApplication.initQgis()

Tags: pyqgis

I am setting the prefix path in Python using the code below. When running the code, a pop-up window stating `python.exe has stopped working` shows up. I've gone line by line in the code within  OsGeo4W shell and it seems that `QgsApplication.initQgis()` is crashing Python.

```
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
print QgsApplication.showSettings()
```

When printing the current settings I get the following paths:

[image]

Comment: Do you have more than one Qgis version installed in OsGeo4W directory? I had a similar problem with a current and the ltr version. After installing the current version the former was renamed to qgis-ltr. I had to change environment variables to ltr, since the current (default) one raises this error.

Comment: I had QGIS installed previously, but have since uninstalled it and reinstalled with QsGeo4W. When printing the current settings I get the paths shown above.

Comment: I run your 4 lines in my installation and get the same result as you, when using Qgis 2.14 (qgis). Starting OSGeo4W64 with qgis-ltr (2.8.7) as QGISNAME it works. I use an additional line `SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%` what seems to be missing in your case (no output in line SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var:)